# Segfault при emit в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Не знаю как можно понятнее описать эту курьезную ситуацию. За все время работы с Qt я пользовался механизмом сигналов/слотов. Но то что происходит сейчас я не могу никак описать. На решение данной проблемы потратил много времени, но так и не пришел ответу.
Итак, есть класс, который работает с БД:

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSql>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDate>
#include <QDebug>

class DataBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QSqlDatabase db;
public:
    explicit DataBase(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~DataBase(){
     db.close();
    }

signals:
    void updateLocationsModel();

public slots:
    /**...**/
    void createLocalPoint(double lat, double lon, QString type);
    void deleteLocalPoint(int id);
};

#endif // DATABASE_H
```

Кусочек его описания:

```
void DataBase::createLocalPoint(double lat, double lon, QString type)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO LocationsPoints (lat, lon, type) VALUES (:lat, :lon, :type);");
    query.bindValue(":lat", lat);
    query.bindValue(":lon", lon);
    query.bindValue(":type", type);

    if (!query.exec()){
        qDebug() << "Error SQLite:" << query.lastError().text();
    }
    emit updateLocationsModel();
}

void DataBase::deleteLocalPoint(int id)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("DELETE FROM LocationsPoints WHERE LocationsPoints.id = :id;");
    query.bindValue(":id", id);
    if (!query.exec()){
        qDebug() << "Error SQLite:" << query.lastError().text();
    }


    qDebug() << query.lastQuery();
    emit updateLocationsModel();
    qDebug() << "++++++";
}
```

**Проблема:** При вызове функции createLocalPoint, код отрабатывает отлично. При вызове deleteLocalPoint спонтанно происходит краш. Никакой здравой логики я не увидел, но попробовал оставить и в той и в той функции одну строку

```
    emit updateLocationsModel();
```

И знаете что? Краш во второй функции остался, а первая как работала так и работает...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не найдя решения, отправился во вкладку отладки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тут что-то проясняется. Во всем, может быть, виноват QML, который я так же активно использую.

Чуток файла main.cpp

```
LocationsModel locationsModel;
QObject::connect(&db, SIGNAL(updateLocationsModel()),
                 &locationsModel, SLOT(updateModel()));
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QQmlContext* ctx = engine.rootContext();
ctx->setContextProperty("locationsModel", &locationsModel);
```

В QML функции вызываются так:

```
dataBase.createLocalPoint(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude, type);
```

И

```
dataBase.deleteLocalPoint(id);
```

Вот так выглядит слот

```
void LocationsModel::updateModel()
{
    QString str_query("SELECT ");
    str_query.append("LocationsPoints.id, ");
    str_query.append("LocationsPoints.lat, ");
    str_query.append("LocationsPoints.lon, ");
    str_query.append("LocationsPoints.type ");
    str_query.append("FROM LocationsPoints; ");

    this->setQuery(str_query);

    qDebug() << str_query << endl;
    qDebug() << "End" << endl;
}
```

Для справки. Экспериментальным путем было установлено, что и deleteLocalPoint  выполняется до конца и emit(Выводится отладочная информация qDebug())

Comment: https://github.com/yashart/neva_project/tree/segfault1 тут есть весь код, но вы его не запустите без БД. В случае если проблема не решится, я заморочусь и выложу .db файл.

P.S. Из-за репутации не разрешили включить ссылку в основной пост.

Comment: Заморочился и запушил в проект файл .bd. Он должен лежать в рабочей директории программы, Qt Creator называет его рабочим каталогом(обычно каталог где лежит папка debug и release). Проблема выявляется, когда вы удаляете установленную метку(покемона). Устанавливается точка на правую кнопку мыши.

Comment: Судя по всему, Вы пытаетесь использовать (читать/писать) память за пределами выделенного объёма. В данном случае, я бы рекомендовал Вам использовать инструмент для поиска таких проблем. В QtCreator под Linux есть встроенная поддержка `valgrind`.

Comment: @alexolut Это, к сожалению, и так очевидно. Я уверен что valgrind здесь добавит порцию геморроя, а вот к однозначному решению не приведет. Ну и там невозможно накосячить с указателями, поэтому улететь в даль памяти не получится. **Еще раз**. Из одной функции работает, из другой - нет, даже если в обеих оставить только emit.

Comment: при наличии ошибок в работе с памятью, проблемы могут проявляться в совершенно неожиданных местах. Valgring вполне мог бы Вам помочь, не понимаю почему Вы от него отказываетесь. Функции имеют как минимум разный набор параметров, сделайте одинаковый и проверьте еще раз. Пробуйте удалять лишний код пока проблема не перестанет проявляться. В крайнем случае можно еще собрать Qt из исходников и более точно ловить точку вылета. Можно еще проверить работоспособность на разных версиях Qt.

Comment: @alexolut Я боюсь, что в случае с QML valgrint будет не лучшим решением. И я напорюсь на функцию внутри qml. Так в принципе и произошло в первый раз. В ходе сегодняшних экспериментов я добился вылета в работоспособной функции, переместив ее туда, где стоит нерабочая. Судя по всему косяк происходит в событии клика мыши для объектов-делегатов.

Answer (score 1):

А вы случайно не из другого потока сообщаете сигналом в QML о том, что у вас что то происходит? Если да, то краши могут быть из за этого. Вам стоит отправлять сигнал не непосредственно в QML, а в какой то объект, работающий в основном же потоке, как и QML, указав при соединеии Qt::DirectConnection. А потом из этого объекта пересыласть сигнал в QML.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Вызывался не из другого потока. Отремонтировал путем изменения алгоритма, действуя по которому пользователь сообщает сигналом.Проще говоря, снял срабатывание сигнала с мыши и установил на кнопку клавиатуры:)